Performance disadvantages of splitting every component into separate chunks in Nuxt?
So I'm working with Nuxt 2.15 (Vue 2.6). Usually if we have a component that is rendered using v-if (so it is not always needed) we import it like this:
  components: {
    SideCategory: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "SideCategory" */
      '~/components/SideCategory.vue')
  },

And in the final build we get a separate JS chunk for this component. And we get it only when it is needed. So it is all fine.
But my question is - is there any potential drawback of importing every component like this?
I saw couple of times in the project I'm working on that components that are always rendered (without v-if) are being lazy imported. And I wonder if maybe it can hurt our performance?
Wouldn't it be better to keep components that are always visible imported normally and let Nuxt/Webpack do its work? Meaning:
import Description from '~/components/Description.vue';
// ...
components: { Description }

Does creating a bunch of small chunks hurt the performance and core web vitals?
I guess it could make it slightly worse, but the difference for a single component would be to small to measure it so I can not validate it easily.

"What do you think?" - this is bad wording for SO, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . Probably suited more for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/ . But it isn't specific for it either. Basically, this depends on your setup and case. The performance will certainly benefit from multiplexing, and suffer if it's served through HTTP 1 instead of 2+. Create a page with many components and decide yourself.
